# Which of the following sentences is correct ; basically I don't understand where to use gerund and where infinitive, and why

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

It is snowing; will you like to go skiing on Saturday or Sunday?

It is snowing ; will you like to go skii on Saturday or Sunday?

(plz reason the answer in simple and discernible way)

Answer (score 1):

We use the *-ing* form of the verb when talking about an activity that generally involves some action in a place other than the home.

So, we can: *Go: skiing, fishing, dancing, hunting, bowling, hiking, skating, shopping, sailing, riding*, etc.

The *ing* form is generally *not* used if no moving about is involved. For example, you do not say:

> ?I am going reading the newspaper.
>
> ?Would you like to go watching the football?

even if you are leaving your house to read in the library or watch in the bar.

But here is where it gets complicated. It is possible to use the infinitive after *go* in:

> Would you like to go watch the football?

but not:

> ?I'm going read the newspaper.

And furthermore there is a difference between common American and British usage. *Go read a book!* or *Go wait outside!* are more likely to be said by an American than a British native speaker. The latter would probably say *Go and read a book!* / *Go and wait outside!*.

And some native speakers may have no problems with sentences such as *Let's go ski tomorrow*. So the issue is not *simple*. As to *discernible*,  if you have a question about a specific *-ing/infinitive* usage in future, I suggest that you do an nGram search on the two alternatives.

This [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20skiing%2C%20go%20ski&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20skiing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20ski%3B%2Cc0) shows clearly that *go skiing* is much the more common usage than *go ski*.

Comment: Although you imply a dialectal difference later on, "Would you like to go watch the football?" is not really acceptable in BrE; it's understood, but it's understood as an Americanism. BrE needs *to go to watch* or *to go and watch.* "Native speaker" really needs qualifying by location.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Thanks for the feedback. You are right that _Would you like to go watch the football?_ is more likely in AmE than BrE. And that it is possible to say _go to watch_ as an alternative to _go watch_ and _go and watch_. But the _go to_ construction does not work for me in _go to wait outside_ or _go to read a book_. The issue is indeed complicated!

Comment: I suspect that *go to...* involves significant movement (to a football ground); where you're only moving to the next room to read, or just outside, *go and...* is more likely.

Comment: @Shoe OK,  now that's been helpful, thanks!

Comment: *Watch the football game*, maybe, or *watch football*, but that *the* there on *football* with nothing following it sounds decidedly odd to me.

Comment: @tchrist. Interesting. _Watch the football game_ sounds a bit tautologous to me. In my example I was thinking of a context where I know that a particular soccer game (hence the definite article) is being shown on a big screen in a nearby bar and ask my brother if he feels like coming with me. (But as a BrE native speaker would ask: _Would you like to go *and* watch the football?_)